# Cant use & in snippets and autocomplete

Tags: sublimetext2

PHP variables that start with $, autocomplete doesn't work for them, even though the snippets exist. So it says for example to start typing '$_' for $*SESSION, but after '$*' nothing comes up.

I also have a problem escaping $ for a javascript function, I used the backslash but it doesn't work.

Can you enable $ in the following snippet?

```
    <content><![CDATA[

function \$(id) {

    return document.getElementById(id);

} ]]></content>
```

Comment: Did you try three escapes -- `\\\$`?

Comment: My guess is autocomplete doesn't work because `$` is defined as a word separator. Try creating a syntax specific setting, with that removed from the `word_separators` setting.

Comment: /// doesnt change anything. how do I change word separator? I mean, that's the way it is when you install it, i'm surprised it doesn't work off the bat. Their own snippets start with $ and dont work.

Comment: I think the function problem was that curly braces need to be escaped as well, but in any case there is no way I found to call a snippet bu typing '$'. For example I made my own $_SESSION snippet but i am calling it with 'ss'.

Comment: You are using forward slashes instead of backward slashes.  Are you sure you want to use forward slashes to escape a special character?

Comment: yea, that was a mistake here I made, I used backward slashes in the code. as I said curly brackets need to be escaped as well, but all in all it seems it is impossible to use '$' as a <tabTrigger>, even though those triggers come with the program.